# Problem of predicting with a loaded tensorflow estimator trained beforehand

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I had trained a tensorflow NN estimator to predict something in Python. And I saved the model in my Google drive via Google colab.

Today, I loaded the model and it was a pretty hard work. I finally succeeded to load the estimator using `tf.compat.v2.saved_model.load` and `.signature` method. it seems WrappedFunction. This is my code till this step.

1. code for saving

```
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
  tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(input_column))
#tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec([input_column]))
export_path = dnn_regressor.export_saved_model('/content/gdrive/My Drive',serving_input_fn)
#https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#savedmodel%EC%9D%98_%EC%A0%9C%EC%96%B4_%ED%9D%90%EB%A6%84
```

2. code for loading

```
imported = tf.compat.v2.saved_model.load('/content/gdrive/My Drive/1572596260', tags=None)
infer = imported.signatures["predict"]
```

But still I fail to put a test data to model to make a prediction.

first, I tried:

```
test_predictions = infer(test_data)
test_predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in test_predictions])
```

And it return an error

> ValueError: All inputs to `ConcreteFunction`s must be Tensors; on invocation >of pruned, the 0-th input ( My data [2513 rows x 45 columns]) was not a >Tensor.

Secondly, looked for some tensorflow document, I wrote this code

```
test_predictions = infer(tf.constant(test_data))
test_predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in test_predictions])
```

This time it return

> The argument 'examples' (value Tensor("Const_10:0", shape=(2513, 45), >dtype=float64)) is not compatible with the shape this function was traced >with. Expected shape (?,), but got shape (2513, 45).
>
> If you called get_concrete_function, you may need to pass a >tf.TensorSpec(..., shape=...) with a less specific shape, having None on axes >which can vary.

I found dynamic/static shape of tensorflow. But I couldn't fully understand those concept and failed to reshaping.
How can I get the result? Thanks.

Comment: I'm in a similar boat. There doesn't appear to be any documentation on how to properly load and use a saved model. If anyone can provide a complete example, it would be very useful!

Comment: I dealt with the problem in other way following this post. It doesn't need reshaping. Hope that it'll be help!  http://shzhangji.com/blog/2018/05/14/serve-tensorflow-estimator-with-savedmodel/